# Should I edit out version numbers from answers regarding software that has reached end of life?

Tags: discussion, language-versions

There is a certain answer I like regarding a PHP question. At the top of the answer the author says in "You can do it in PHP >= 5.6 like this...". However PHP 5.6 is in the end-of-life stage and has not been supported even with security fixes [for quite a while now](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php).

So I was thinking I could revise the introductory sentence to just say "You can do it like this...". This solution does work in the latest version and I find it very unlikely that this would stop working.

I am wondering what is the consensus for this approach?

Comment: I don't understand what this gains you. Does the answer work prior to PHP 5.6? Does it work for any versions after it? Do remember that being out of support doesn't mean nobody uses it. If the version number is valuable information, then why edit it out? If it's not then it's probably fine.

Comment: @VLAZ Just to remove the extra noise. Some people might think that this answer doesn't apply for some reason so just I want to make it more noticeable. Plus this question was a general question and not targeted to a specific version.

Comment: @VLAZ I do believe it would work in any version after it.

Comment: This information was missing in your writeup here. You just said 5.6 is out of support and I have no way of knowing if the solution works in newer versions.

Comment: @VLAZ I updated my question with that. My primary motivation for wanting to delete it is similar to the reason why we edit out things like "Hello.." or "thanks in advance"

Comment: As I said, if it's not valuable, then it can probably be removed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not noise. Noise is verbiage devoid of technical value. Because who isn't "thankful for everyone's answers" and whatnot?

A (hopefully) small minority of people will be working with ancient versions like that. Others may be curious to know what version it was added for other reasons (eg older features have more example code out there).

Leave it. It doesn't take up that much space anyway.

---

PS, PHP 7.4 is not the latest version. PHP 8.0 was released nearly a year ago and 8.1 comes out in a few weeks.

Comment: Fair enough. Perhaps we can revisit when (if?) [version labels](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370640/version-labels-for-answers) gets off the ground

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a good idea to change it to *"You can achieve it using the ..."*

The second highest voted answer can be changed to include the phrase *"Prior to PHP 5.6, this could be achieved with ..."*

When doing so, think about what would be most useful for the community without losing any information.